# Compute $i\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{(1-z^2)^2}{z^2(1+6z+z^2)} \ dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I was inspired to try and solve the integral from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091960/complex-integration-int-pi-pi-frac-sin2-t3-cos-tdt/1092011#1092011) post. When I get to computing the residues for $z_2=\sqrt{8}-3$ I run into troubles.

We see that $z_1=0$ is a pole of order $2$ and $z_2=\sqrt{8}-3$ is the only simple pole that is inside of the unit circle. Letting

$$f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}=\frac{(1-z^2)^2}{z^2(1+6z+z^2)} $$ we have that

$$\text{Res}_{z_1}(f)=\frac{g'(z_1)}{(2-1)!}=\frac{2(z_1^2-1)\cdot 2z_1}{1}=0.$$

For the other residue, we can use

$$\text{Res}_{z_2}(f)=\frac{g(z_2)}{h'(z_2)}=\frac{(1-z_2^2)^2}{z_2^2(1+6z_2+z_2^2)}=...$$

When the arithmetic becomes complicated I just give up and assume the method is incorrect. Is this just a mean problem or am I missing something important here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases you are doing a couple mistakes. In the first the function $g(z)$ is actually $$g(z)=\frac{(1-z^2)^2}{1+6z+z^2}$$
and $h(z)=z^2$
whereas in the second case
$$g(z)=\frac{(1-z^2)^2}{z^2}$$
and $h(z)=1+6z+z^2$, so $h'(z)=2z+6$

From here the calculation goes as follows: in the first case
The residue is
$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{g}{f},0\right)=g'(0)=\frac{-4z(1-z^2)}{1+6z+z^2}-\frac{(1-z^2)^2\cdot(6+2z)}{(1+6z+z^2)^2}\ \Big|_{z=0}=-6$$
whereas in the second
$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{g}{f},z_2\right)=\frac{g(z_2)}{h'(z_2)}=\frac{(1-z_2^2)^2}{z_2^2(2z_2+6)},$$
and here you plug in your value for $z_2$.

[WA tells me](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1-(sqrt(8)-3)%5E2)%5E2%2F((sqrt(8)-3)%5E2(2(sqrt(8)-3)%2B6))) the residue at $z_2$ is just $4\sqrt{2}$.

So in total we got that the integral equals

$$i\cdot2\pi i\cdot(4\sqrt{2}-6)=2\pi i\cdot(6-4\sqrt{2}).$$

Comment: I get wrong answer when I do the second one :S I even plugged it in with maple and it gave me the incorrect answer.

Comment: I don't know... the root you found is correct and now it's just a matter of plugging it in.

Comment: @Parseval. I've added in the result from WA

Answer (score 3):

Your method is incorrect. The correct formula for computing the residue at $0$ (since it is indeed a pole of order $2$) is:$$\frac1{(2-1)!}\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\mathrm d\frac{(1-z^2)^2}{1+6z+z^2}}{\mathrm dz}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{2 \left(z^2-1\right) \left(z^3+9 z^2+3 z+3\right)}{\left(z^2+6z+1\right)^2}=-6.$$